# How to validate user creation on the server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, client-server, meteor

What is the best approach to validate user creation on the client and server?

I've tried to validate user creation both server and client side. First I've used methods and `Accounts.createUser` function but it didn't work even that the documentation says it should.

I've tried different approach. I used `Accounts.createUser` to validate it on the client and `Account.onCreateUser` on the server. The problem is that I can't validate password because it's encrypted.

So what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Wrapping `Accounts.createUser` in a meteor method call should return you a userId and in terms of validation, i have been running a regex on the client/server side

Comment: On the server everything seems to work but on the client I get empty error object in the callback function of the `Accounts.createUser` function. Seems to be some kind of error or maybe I shouldn't use `Accounts.createUser` in Methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For validation of new users, see [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_validatenewuser)

Example from the docs:

```
// Validate username, sending a specific error message on failure.
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
    if (user.username && user.username.length >= 3)
        return true;
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Username must have at least 3 characters");
});
// Validate username, without a specific error message.
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
    return user.username !== "root";
});
```

Comment: I must be missing something, because it seems validateNewUser is called after onCreateUser (where I initialize stuff related to the newly created user).

Comment: Anyway I ended up using only onCreateUser(). Don't forget to pass a HTTP error code as first param of the exception, otherwise the message won't show up with accounts-ui.